# How to check contents of an XML NodeList

Tags: python, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname, nodelist

This may be a simple question, but how can I, using Python, check if a *NodeList* returned by *getElementsByTagName* has any contents?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#nodelist-objects), NodeList provides a `.item(i)` method and a `.length` attribute that can be accessed by a client object.